# Error while subscribing App from WSO2 App manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I made the configurations as per the [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM100/Integrating+a+Mobile+Device+Manager). But as I try to subscribe the app from the android mobile,I get the error as `ERROR - MDMOperationsImpl Cannot connect to Token API Endpoint
ERROR - MDMOperationsImpl No OK response received form the API`. Is there any other configurations to be done to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the scenario you are trying to perform and the EMM version that you use.

EMM 2.0.0 now has in built AppM features which allow EMM to be used without integrating with AppM, in case publishing of only mobile applications is required. If you need to publish both web and mobile applications you will have to integrate AppM with EMM.

In the document you have refered above , section [1] applies to EMM 2.0.0 and above and section [2] applies to versions below 2.0.0

From the error you have mentioned, the issue seems to be related to the following property.

```
<Property name="TokenApiURL">https://localhost:9448/oauth2/token</Property>
```

Can you check whether this URL contains the correct host and port ( 9443 + port offset) of EMM .

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM100/Integrating+a+Mobile+Device+Manager#IntegratingaMobileDeviceManager-IntegratingWSO2MDM

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/APPM100/Integrating+a+Mobile+Device+Manager#IntegratingaMobileDeviceManager-IntegratingWSO2EMM